# Normalizing data between 0 and 1

Tags: normalization

I am a novice when it comes to stats, so I apologize beforehand for the simplicity of my question.

I trying to figure out the best way to normalize (this may be the wrong term) my data in so that the maximum value is 1 and the minimum value is 0. What are my options and what methods would you suggest as the best?

My data will be non-negative and has no bound (though it may be bound in some situations, how would this make it different?).

I am measuring content across many different dimensions and I want to be able to make comparisons in terms of how relevant a given piece of content is. Additionally, I want to display values across these dimensions that is explicable and easily understood.

Thank you in advance for helping a newbie :)